# Cannot catch string with regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to capture the text inside `span` with [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/rK7bO8/4). But I can't figure why this doesn't work.

**String**

```
<span class="text">mas Deus disse: ‘Não comam do fruto da árvore que está no meio do jardim, nem toquem nele; do contrário vocês morrerão’ &quot;.</span>
```

**Regex**

```
<span class=\"text\">([a-zA-Z%$#@*+=§ß|,.:;!?&\-_()\[\]\/\\{}ÁáÉéÍíÓóÚúÂâÊêÔôçãõÄäËëÏïÖöÜüÀà\"\'‘’ªº ]+)<\/span>
```

What is wrong?

Comment: I've noticed that if I remove the `&quot;` from the string everything goes fine...

Comment: What is the language/tool? Anyway, if you are using JavaScript, you can totally use DOM to pick out the text node.

Comment: @nhahtdh I'm working with Python3.

Comment: Please use BeautifulSoup for parsing HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding the allowed characters to your class it might be better readable and maintainable to exclude the characters that are not allowed by using a [negated class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) if that's an option for you!

```
<span\s+class=\"text\">([^<]+)<\/span>
```

- `[^<]+` matches one or more characters, that are not `<`
- `\s+` matches one or more whitespaces `[ \t\r\n\f]`.

[See demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/dZ3iK6/1)

Comment: This is not safe. https://regex101.com/r/dZ3iK6/3. Even for a quick hack, whitelisting chars is a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your  `&quot;`. The fix is simply add the invisible space into your regex, `<span class=\"text\">([a-zA-Z%$#@*+=§ß|,.:;!?&\-_()\[\]\/\\{}ÁáÉéÍíÓóÚúÂâÊêÔôçãõÄäËëÏïÖöÜüÀà\"\'‘’ªº  ]+)<\/span>` Notice that stackoverlow will convert the weird space into plain space, so pasting the regex in this answer will not work. You have to paste it from your code in this [link](https://regex101.com/r/rK7bO8/5)

Paste your text in vim and search for (plain space), the space in  `&quot;` is not highlighted. Inspecting the weird space shows that it is a `&nbsp`, with char code 240. Reference: http://www.ascii-code.com/

[image]

**Disclaimer**: 
  Regex is not for parsing html. But it seems op is doing quick scraping, I think using regex in this case is fine.

Comment: Or, you can try this regex, with hex escape code. `<span class=\"text\">([a-zA-Z%$#@*+=§ß|,.:;!?&\-_()\[\]\/\\{}ÁáÉéÍíÓóÚúÂâÊêÔôçãõÄäËëÏïÖöÜüÀà\"\'‘’ªº \xa0]+)<\/span>`